# Integrating an Uncountable Product Measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Imagine I have an uncountable number of probability spaces $X_i = (\Omega_i, B_i, \mu_i)$ indexed by $i \in [0,1]$. Kolomogorov's extension theorem tells us that we can define a product measure $\mu$ on the product space $\prod_{i \in [0,1]} X_i $.

Let $A_i  \subset X_i$ be a measurable set, and let $A = \bigcup_{i \in [0,1]} (A_i \times (\prod_{j \neq i} X_j))$. I want to show that
$$\mu(A) = \int_0^1 \mu_i(A_i) \, di$$
but I'm not sure whether this is actually true.

Comment: This cannot be true ($\mu$ would not change if instead of $[0,1]$ there were $\Bbb R$, or $[-1,1]$, or a set devoid of measure-theoretic structure like the cardinal $\beth_1$) and, more importantly, your $A$ is hardly ever measurable.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by hardly-ever measurable?

Comment: "Hardly ever" isn't a technical term. I mean its [natural language](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/hardly-ever-rarely-scarcely-seldom) meaning of "never, except a few rare instances".